# parsing a mmap()-ed file

Tags: c++, c, parsing

What would be the best (fastest) way to parse through a mmap-ed file? It contains pairs of data (string int), but I cannot persume number of whitespaces/tabs/newlines between them.

Comment: what do you mean by "parse" - what is stored in the file and what are you trying to do? This question is too vague to answer as it stands...

Comment: @Martin You know that strtok modifies the "source", right? So if you use it on your mmap, you are modifying the file! Is your file text only or binary or what? What type of parsing do you want?

Comment: Voting to close. It is impossible to understand what is being asked here

Comment: Define _best_: if it the fastest or easiest to code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've mmaped the whole file in (rather than chunks - as that would make life awefully complicated), I'd do something like the following...

```
// Effectively this wraps the mmaped block
std::istringstream str;
str.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(<pointer to start of mmaped block>, <size of mmaped block>);

std::string sv;
std::string iv;

while(str >> sv >> iv)
{
  // do stuff...
}
```

I think that should work...

**WARNING** This is implementation defined behaviour, see [this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/636019) for an altogether better approach.

Comment: As I recall, `std::basic_streambuf::setbuf` is protected.

Comment: As it turns out, this is implementation-defined: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/636019

Answer (score 2):

If by best/fastest you mean easiest to code, then this is one of those rare occasions where the deprecated `std::istrstream` fits the bill perfectly; call the `istrstream::istrstream(char const*, std::streamsize)` constructor overload then extract the data from the stream as you would from any other `std::istream`. (This won't duplicate the underlying memory like `std::istringstream` will.)

If by best/fastest you mean best/fastest runtime performance, I don't think you'll be able to beat [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials.html) or a handwritten parser, though the former would be much easier to write and maintain in my opinion (library learning curve aside, if you've never used boost.spirit before).

Comment: @Nim When it fits, it fits. :-]

Comment: @Nim Better, yes, absolutely; "easiest to code", as was my qualification, no. But then I'd regard using boost.spirit.qi "better" than either stream-based route, personally.

Comment: I'd go with spirit too, but one of my favourite sayings applies here, sometimes all you need is a fly-swatter.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Parsing string/integer pairs (i.e. foo 50 bar 20 baz 123) separated by whitespace should be lightning fast either way. The by far more important factors will be that
a) the pages are actually in RAM, which mmap alone does not guarantee
b) cache lines are in the L1 cache

While mmap does already read ahead by default on sequential access, disk access is in the *tens of milliseconds*,and parsing over a 4k page of memory is (ideally) in the tens of microseconds.
So, you cannot expect the prefetcher to keep pace, especially since it will only prefetch whenever it looks like you will need more (which, even assuming seek time is zero, practically guarantees an upfront cost due to rotational delay on a mechanical disk).
Therefore, unless your total data is only a dozen kilobytes (in which case the question about how to do it as fast as possible would be pointless, anyway), it makes sense to madvise(MADV_WILLNEED) before you start your scan, so the operating system won't wait to see its heuristics triggered by your access pattern, but reads in sequentially what it can without cease. Disk bandwidth (sequentially), is huge once you're past the access time. You will still probably catch up, but much later. If your dataset is large enough so it will probably not fit into RAM, calling MADV_DONTNEED on data you've already seen every now and then is a good idea.

The same that is true for page faults is true for cache misses. A load from cache is 1-2 cycles, a load from memory is something around 200-500 cycles.
CPUs have automatic prefetching for sequential access patterns, however they are limited.
First, prefetching never occurs across a page boundary. That is because if this were the case, then automatic prefetching would regularly trigger page faults which would be very unpleasing.
Second, prefetching happens only after two consecutive misses, this is to ensure that prefetching really only kicks in when it probably makes sense. Prefetching the adjacent cache lines for every random read would be stupid as it would needlessly trash valuable cache lines.
Third, prefetching takes time, and once the heuristics in the CPU trigger, you're already racing it for the data, so sooner is better than later.
Luckily, *you know* what data you will be wanting, and you know it a long time ahead. Therefore, you can give prefetch hints, which will give the CPU a valuable head start (prefetch e.g. half a kilobyte ahead).

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your question is too vague to be answered.

Nonetheless, if all you need to do is to get some data out of the file, what you *don't* want to do is to use a method that would modify memory in the `mmap`ed region.

**Edit** It's much clearer now that you've edited the question. As a starting point, I'd use a single `char` pointer to iterate over the entire `mmap`ed file. Extracting strings is very straightforward (the exact method depends on what you need to do with the result) and the integers can be extracted with `atoi` et al.

Answer (score 0):

You could access it via a `std::string` and use `std::istringstream` in order to read from it sequentially. Or use some more convenient library, e.g. in Qt you could use a `QTextStream` on a `QByteArray` constructed from the mmaped memory.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but wasn't able to mmap it to a std::string. How could I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the `string::string ( const char * s, size_t n );` constructor would just reference. But obviously it does a copy (`const char *`...). `QByteArray::fromRawData()` however allows you to operate on an existing chunk of memory. However, you need to guarantee lifetime of that chunk during the lifetime of that `QByteArray`.